# gstreamer stop streaming on silence

Tags: gstreamer

I have two terminals open on my ubuntu machine. The idea is to speak into the microphone and then play it back over the speaker. On the first terminal I set up a gstreamer speaker with the command:

gst-launch-0.10 pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1,depth=16,width=16,rate=22000 ! rtpL16pay  ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000

the listener on the other terminal i use this command

gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)22000, width=16, height=16, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, channel-positions=(int)1, payload=(int)96" ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink sync=false

What i want to now do is start the code, and automatically stop the stream when there is no sound for about 2 second. How should i go about doing this?

Comment: hi, did you find any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Udpsrc has a property called "timeout", by setting this property the element will post a message on the pipeline bus in case no package is received in a specific lapse of time. Your receiving pipeline should look something like this:

gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=5000  timeout=2000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)22000, width=16, height=16, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, channel-positions=(int)1, payload=(int)96" ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink sync=false

The bus callback then should look something like this:

```
gboolean
bus_callback (GstBus * bus, GstMessage * message, gpointer data)
{
  GError *error;
  gchar *parsed_txt;
  const GstStructure *st = gst_message_get_structure (message);
  const gchar *typename = GST_MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME (message);
  const gchar *srcname = GST_MESSAGE_SRC_NAME (message);

  GST_LOG ("New %s message from %s: %s", typename, srcname, 
       st ? gst_structure_get_name(st) : "(null)");

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (message)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_INFO:
      gst_message_parse_info (message, &error, &parsed_txt);
      g_print ("%s\n", parsed_txt);
      g_free (parsed_txt);
      g_error_free (error);
      break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
      gst_message_parse_error (message, &error, &parsed_txt);
      GST_ERROR ("%s (%s)", error->message,
          parsed_txt ? parsed_txt : "no debug info");
      if (parsed_txt)
        g_free (parsed_txt);
    GST_DEBUG ("No error handling callback registered");

      break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT:
      /* We don't care for messages other than timeouts */
      if (!gst_structure_has_name (st, "GstUDPSrcTimeout"))
    break;
    GST_WARNING ("Timeout received from udpsrc");
    gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT (pipeline),GST_STATE_NULL));
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
```

Good Luck!